# Why can't I remove event listeners using off()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to remove dynamically an event from the DOM. For this, I am using Chrome (version 79) dev tools, on page https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/category/news?utm_source=menu

In the Elements tab, I go to Event Listeners, and look for the 'load' event, and I find 3 events on the Window element. So in the console, I type:

```
$(window).off('load');
```

The command executes with no error, but nothing seemed to have changed, even when I press the refresh button in the events section. I am expecting all the 'load' events for Window to disappear.

[image]

I have this same problem on many other sites, but works fine on my local webpage (this is how I know I am using JQuery the right way)...

Comment: "*even when I press the refresh button*" refreshing the page will re-execute all the JavaScript on it, including adding any event handlers.

Comment: With `.off` you can remove only listeners attached by jQuery.

Comment: Keep in mind sometimes `window.` properties won't work the way you expect when you type them in the console, because the console is (for certain purposes) a separate window object from the one holding your document.

Comment: @NathanHawks I don't think that is the case. The console doesn't have its own `window` object.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I came about this "knowledge" via the behavior of localStorage, but maybe it's a special case. At least in JSFiddle, an app with working localStorage returns undefined's in the console. But I could be reading too much into a quirk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove an existing listener, use [getEventListeners](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities#geteventlisteners) command line API:

```
getEventListeners(window).load.forEach(x=>window.removeEventListener('load',x.listener))
```

or simply click the `Remove` button in Elements `Event listeners` panel:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I already knew about the "remove" button, but I wanted to do find a javascript way to do so.

Answer (score 2):

[`.off()`](https://api.jquery.com/off/) only removes events that were added via the `.on()` method, so any events added with other APIs wouldn't be affected.

Now, when you say *even when I press the refresh button in the events section. I am expecting all the 'load' events for Window to disappear.*, you misunderstand the nature of how a page is processed. If you refresh the page, all of its code is processed again, therefore even if you were successful in removing the handlers in your console, they would all come back because the page is starting all over again.

Understand that what you do in the console only affects the current instance of the page loaded within the browser.

Comment: The OP probably clicks the reload icon in the event listeners panel, not the page reload icon.

Comment: I meant to say "refreshed the event listeners", using the refresh button in the image I showed. Not the whole page, obviously.